# Why can't I re-assign the parent's variable with this program?

Tags: java, inheritance, this, variable-assignment, super

```
package accesslevelmodifiers;

public class AccessLevelModifiers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Parent parent =new Parent();
    Subclass subclass = new Subclass();
    parent.go();
    subclass.go();

    System.out.println("===========");

    subclass.setNumberPu(3);
    parent.go();
    subclass.go();
    }
}


public class Parent {

    public int NumberPu=100;

    public void go(){
        System.out.println(NumberPu);
    }
}

class Subclass extends Parent{

    public void setNumberPu(int NumberPu) {
        super.NumberPu = NumberPu;
    }


}
```

It was successfully built and run; however the result was

```
 100
 100
 ===========
 100
 3
```

I am confused by two things. 
1.Why can I use super.NumberPu in the subclass? I mean if I write

```
class Subclass extends Parent{
        super.NumberPu = 3;   
}
```

IDE will say cannot find symbol.

2. I used super so I thought the value of NumberPu in parent will be assigned as 3, but instead it was the one in subclass that is assigned. Can anyone tell me what happened? How come super. became this. ?
   Thank you so much!

Comment: How many objects do you think you have here, of what types?

Comment: I have two instances parent and subclass here, and I have two objects NumberPu(int type) in parent and NumberPu(int type) in subclass. Am I correct?

Comment: You are not.  This  `new Parent()` creates an object of type `Parent`.  This `new Subclass()` creates an object of type `Subclass`. Both of those objects have access to their own `NumberPu` field.

Comment: Thank you for explaining!! So I have two objects here (parent and subclass) and they belong to Parent and Subclass types respectively. Object parent is the instance of Parent class while Object subclass is the instance of Subclass class. I guess this sounds better??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two *different* objects here, so when you change the number of one of them, the other one doesn't change because they're **unrelated**.

```
Parent parent =new Parent();
Subclass subclass = new Subclass();
```

See how you're using `new` here? The `new` operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. So you have two different pieces of memory, completely unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I got your meanings!

Comment: @Oscar no problem! Remember, if my answer answered your question, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer as the solution, so other people with your problem know the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put declarations at the class level (for example to add a new variable to your subclass) but not statements. Here you're not declaring a new variable, your assigning a value to an existing one, so it should be done in the constructor, that's fine.
2. you're confusing classes and instances. Your parent and your subclass objects are two different instances, modifying one does not impact the other, they are two different objects with different member field instances. `super` is a way to reference the fields from the super class in case of ambiguities, `this` is to reference the current instance, so they're at two different levels.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understand the meaning of assigning a value to an existing one should be done in the constructor. However I still don't understand what does super.NumberPu refer to? I should have changed it into this.NumberPu to get the result above.

Comment: in your case, super.NumberPu and this.NumberPu refer to the same thing: the field NumberPu, defined in the superclass of SubClass, for the current instance.

Comment: So can I say in the object subclass, there is only one field called NumberPu. NumberPu is shared by two classes: Parent, the one that declares it. And Subclass, the one who inherits it from Parent? So when I reassign the value of NumberPu, it doesn't matter whether I use this. or super. because they all refer to the only one?